# Overlay Video in AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, overlay, calayer, video-processing

AVFoundation is not adding an overlay to my video. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried making the overlay completely white but it is not getting placed on the video. When the video plays it must play the AVMutableComposition Track and not exporter.videoComposition that I add. I am not experienced enough with AVFoundation to know what is going wrong.

```
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

// 3 - Video track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
 //    [videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,self.videoAsset.duration)
//                        ofTrack:[[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
//                         atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    CMTime insertTime = kCMTimeZero;
    for(AVURLAsset *videoAsset in self.videoArray){
        [videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:insertTime error:nil];

        // Updating the insertTime for the next insert
        insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAsset.duration);
    }

// 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = videoTrack.timeRange;

// 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[videoTrack.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
}
[videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:videoTrack.timeRange.duration];

// 3.3 - Add instructions
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
}

float renderWidth, renderHeight;
renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

   // [self applyVideoEffectsToComposition:mainCompositionInst size:naturalSize];
    // 1 - set up the overlay
    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    UIImage *overlayImage = nil;
    //overlayLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlayImage.png"];


    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoTrack.naturalSize.width, videoTrack.naturalSize.height);
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    // 2 - set up the parent layer
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoTrack.naturalSize.width, videoTrack.naturalSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoTrack.naturalSize.width, videoTrack.naturalSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

    // 3 - apply magic
    mainCompositionInst.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];


// 4 - Get path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

// 5 - Create exporter
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                  presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //[self exportDidFinish:exporter];
        //do stuff

    });
}];
```

Comment: @VijayKachhadiya Hey I tried the tutorial you posted but it still is not working. This is my code. Thought you might be able to help.

Answer (score 8):

I am not an expert in Objective-C. I am currently doing an iOS project (in Swift 3) which requires text overlay onto video with specific time range. Below code is perfectly working in my project. You can try it. Your video is saved in documents directory. So you must delete temporary video file when exporting. Below code, I am exporting the video into my photo Library. So you need to Import **Photos** Framework.

```
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: urlVideo!, options: nil)

    let track =  asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoTrack:AVAssetTrack = track[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)

    let compositionVideoTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(timerange, of: videoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    for audioTrack in asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) {
        do {
            try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }

    let size = videoTrack.naturalSize

    //print("Size of vieo: \(size)")

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.string = "Text Overlay Test"
    textLayer.fontSize = 35
    textLayer.font = "Baskerville-BoldItalic" as CFTypeRef
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    textLayer.opacity = 0
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter


    textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: size.width, height: size.height / 6)





    // making a time range to show text
    let fadeInAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    fadeInAnimation.duration = 10
    fadeInAnimation.fromValue = Int(1.0)
    fadeInAnimation.toValue = Int(1.0)
    fadeInAnimation.beginTime = 3
    fadeInAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    textLayer.add(fadeInAnimation, forKey: "opacity")


    // video layer making

    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(textLayer)

    // adding the magic
    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    layercomposition.renderSize = size
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration)
    let videotrack = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerinstruction]
    layercomposition.instructions = [instruction]

    //  create new file to receive data
    let mergedVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/mergedVideo.mp4")

    // must delete existing temporary file from file directory, also use try catch
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: mergedVideoURL as URL)
        print("Tyr Excepted")
    } catch _ as NSError {
        print("Error")
    }



    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    guard let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {return}
    assetExport.videoComposition = layercomposition
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = mergedVideoURL as URL
    assetExport.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
        default:
            print("Exported")
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: mergedVideoURL as URL)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }


        }
    })
```